# Uniform boundedness principle for lower semicontinuous functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

If $f$ i a lower semi-continuous function, the pre-images $\{x: f(x) \leq c\}$ are closed. Is it correct that the following form of the uniform boundedness principle can be generalized to functions that are just lower semi-contimnuous?

> Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $\mathcal{F}$ be a
>   collection of continuous, complex valued functions such that $\forall
>   x \in X$ $\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} |f(x)| < + \infty$. Then there is
>   an $n_0>0$ and an open ball $B_0 \subset X$ such that $\forall f \in
>   \mathcal{F}, \ x  \in B_0, \sup_{x \in B_0} |f(x)| \leq n_0$.
>
> **Proof.** 
>   Form the sets $C_n = \{x \in X: \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}}|f(x)|\leq
>  n\}$. The sets $C_n$ are closed since the $f$'s are continuous and
>   $C_n= \bigcap_{f\in \mathcal{F}} \{x \in X: |f(x)|\leq n\}$(the
>   continuous preimage of a closed set is closed and an arbitrary
>   intersection of closed sets is closed).
>
> Moreover since $\forall x \in X \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}}|f(x)| <
>  +\infty$,  $X=\bigcup_{n\geq0}C_n$. Since $X$ is complete Baire's Category theorem tells us that there is some $n_0$ and an open ball
>   with $B_0 \subset C_{n_0}$. Let $f \in \mathcal{F}$. For all $x \in
>   B_0 \ \ |f(x)|\leq n_0 \implies \sup_{x \in B_0} |f(x)| \leq n_0$ -
>   which is what was to be proven.

Comment: What does lower semi-continuity mean in the context of complex-valued functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the fact cannot be generalized to lower semi-continuous functions in the same form.

#### A counterexample

Take $X = \mathbb{R}$ and let $\{ q_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ be an enumeration of all rationals. Consider the family $\mathcal{F} = \{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ where $f_n : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined as

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} -n & \text{if } x = q_n \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} = -n \cdot \chi_{\{ q_n \}}(x).$$

Then every $f \in \mathcal{F}$ is lower semi-continuous. Also for each $x \in X$ there is at most one $f \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$, hence $\displaystyle \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} |f(x)| < \infty$.

But for an arbitrary $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ the set

$$A = \{ x \in X : (\exists f \in \mathcal{F}) \, |f(x)| > n_0 \} = \{ q_n : n > n_0 \}$$

is dense in $X$, so there is no open ball $B \subseteq X$ disjoint from $A$.

#### Where does the proof fail?

The proof fails, because for each $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f \in \mathcal{F}$ the set $\{ x \in X : f(x) \leqslant n_0 \}$ is closed by the lower semi-continuity, but for the set

$$\{ x \in X : |f(x)| \leqslant n_0 \} = \{ x \in X : -n_0 \leqslant f(x) \leqslant n_0 \}$$

to be closed, full continuity is required due to the inequality from below.

#### A weaker generalization

The proof goes through if we demand a weaker conclusion:

> Let $(X, d)$ be a complete metric space and $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of lower semi-continuous, real-valued functions such that $\displaystyle (\forall x \in X) \, \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} f(x) < \infty$.
>   Then there is $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and an open ball $B \subseteq X$ such that $\displaystyle (\forall x \in B) \, \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} f(x) \leqslant n_0$.